# BizTalk orchestration: My messages are not shown in Transform settings

Tags: xml, web-services, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I am writing a BizTalk orchestration which involves a set of messages (which are input/output of some web-services). I want to perform transform on these messages but when adding "Transform" to my orch. it only lists input and output messages of the orchestration as source/destination!

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: are you try to map a web service response? if yes then what is the type of result

Comment: I am trying to map orchestration input to web-service input. web-service input message contains only primitive data types (I think this is important in the process of defining a map but I have not yet discovered the real problem).

Comment: Use message assignment shape to create the request. With no complex type defined at service, you won't be able to use map

Comment: "Use of unconstructed message in message assignment" is the error message I receive when I try to initialize a message using message assignment

Answer (score 0):

The Transform Configuration dialog box will only list messages that match the message type of your BTS mapping.

Typically, you have your mapping which maps between message type A and message type B. Here, you are selecting the destination message type. If your message is not listed here, it means it does not have the same message type as your BTS mapping expects it to be in it's destination schema.

Make sure you select the correct message type for your message in your orchestration or - if you are sure that this matches - double check the destination of your BTS mapping.
Either way, there will be a discrepancy between the two.

Comment: But we can ask VS to create a new BTS mapping based on the source/destination message type and that's what I am using. In this case I have to be able to select any message type and the map will be created accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Messages of the XmlDocument Type will not appear in the Transform dialog.

Comment: But those are based on web-service request/response and all of them have schema.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the web service request with primitive types should be created in message assignment shape, not the maps

Comment: But message assignment cannot "CREATE" a new message. It can only assign values to an existing message.

Comment: That's not correct to say. A message can be created by either Map, or within message assignment shape as both appears within Construct Message http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253554(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: The link in the comment is gone. Messages can be created by creating a system.xml.xmlDocument, loading it from an xml string or file, then assigning the xmldocument variable to the message.